# the counter mode of encryption CTR - AES

Tags: encryption, aes

> To attack an encryption algorithm, you ask the encryption oracle to
>   encrypt a polynomial number of messages of your choice and observe the
>   outputs. Then, you give the oracle two messages m0 and m1. The oracle
>   will choose one of the messages uniformly at random, encrypts it, and
>   return the ciphertext c to you. The encryption algorithm is said to be
>   broken if you can determine to which one of the two messages the
>   ciphertext corresponds. Assuming the counter is 48-bit long and the
>   used block cipher is AES (recall that AES operates on 128-bit blocks)
>   answer the following questions:
>
> a. Assume the counter is always zero (i.e., the counter does not
>   change from block to block). Can you come up with a successful attack
>   against this mode of encryption?
>
> b. Assume now the nonce is fixed (i.e., the nonce does not change from
>   message to message). Can you come up with a successful attack against
>   this mode of encryption?
>
> c. What is the maximum length of the messages that can be encrypted
>   using this mode?
>
> d. In the counter mode of encryption, the nonce cannot be used again
>   unless a new block cipher key is chosen. What is the maximum number of
>   messages that can be encrypted using the same key?

Comment: Posting hw questions here is a waste of your time, our time, and your lecturer's time.

Comment: I see your homework/assignment, but I can't detect ***your*** question. Therefore, it's unclear what you are asking. What research have you done? What have you tried? Where exactly did you get stuck solving this? Please edit your question accordingly. I'll be happy to reopen it once you do.

Comment: I copied  the  whole question.

Comment: @AFB "This is not a homework solving service. What have you tried? What do you not understand about these questions?"

Comment: @AFB You indeed copied the whole question/assignment/homework (nothing really new there), but you still fail to describe ***your own question*** related to it. This results in the question still being off-topic as ***it’s still unclear what you are asking*** (and not the person who wrote the question/assignment/homework you are quoting). Again – What research have you done? What have you tried? Where exactly did you get stuck solving this? Please edit your question accordingly to pull this on-topic. One thing is clear: no one will do your work and solve the quoted assignment/homework for you.

Comment: sure , but I want some related topics ,, because I read about AES and CTR encryption mode , but until now I can't find a relation to calculate the length of the message . All I need some hints.

Comment: the size of counter is less than the size of plaintext .. I don't understand how I will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions were directly copied form a text book. This is not a homework solving service. The following hints should help you understand the questions. What have you tried? What do you not understand about these questions?

---

> a. Assume the counter is always zero (i.e., the counter does not
>   change from block to block). Can you come up with a successful attack
>   against this mode of encryption?

CTR with a fixed counter is worse than ECB. Penguins anyone?

> b. Assume now the nonce is fixed (i.e., the nonce does not change from
>   message to message). Can you come up with a successful attack against
>   this mode of encryption?

Key-nonce reuse is critical. Especially with a stream cipher like AES-CTR. What happens when you use a one-time pad twice?

> c. What is the maximum length of the messages that can be encrypted
>   using this mode?

How large is a single block?

How many blocks can a block cipher in counter mode produce?

> d. In the counter mode of encryption, the nonce cannot be used again
>   unless a new block cipher key is chosen. What is the maximum number of
>   messages that can be encrypted using the same key?

How many different nonces are there?

Comment: ‘CTR’ with a fixed counter is not ~ECB—it's much worse than that.  $\operatorname{AES-ECB}_k(a \mathbin\Vert b) = \operatorname{AES}_k(a) \mathbin\Vert \operatorname{AES}_k(b)$, but $\operatorname{AES-CTRLOLWUPS}_k(a \mathbin\Vert b) = (a \oplus p) \mathbin\Vert (b \oplus p)$, where $p = \operatorname{AES}_k(0)$.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Er yes of course.

Comment: I think c is the maximum message size of 2^32 blocks but I am not sure

Comment: about d .. the number of messages encrypted under a single key is small. but I can not specify a number???

Comment: Please revise your question with respect to e-sushi's comment on the question.

Comment: ok ,it is my H.W but you don't need to give the answer, I want some help by giving me just  hints .

Comment: @AFB I did provide hints. If these hints are not enough. You need to expand on **your** question. We know the homework questions. We do not know **your** questions.

Comment: @AFB Have you asked your classmates or lecturer or textbook? These questions do not come without references.

Comment: I read in the reference of our course and I googled and read about AES-CTR mode from many websites. I tried to solve but I am not sure about the last two questions

Comment: We do not see your attempts to solve it. We do not see what parts of these questions you do not understand. My hints above are sufficient to reconstruct this. All edit for another hint...

Comment: @AFB I've updated my answer.

Comment: ok. I see. because he said (the nonce cannot be used again unless a new block cipher key is chosen) , so I think  one message is allowed

Comment: @AFB The counter bounds the maximum size per message. The nonce bounds the number of messages. You have more than 1 nonce, so you have more than one message per key.